# What should I specify as --tag parameter in Android SDK's avdmanager?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, avd-manager

As GUI tools are gone in recent versions of Android SDK and I don't want to use their Android Studio IDE, I'm trying to create virtual device for emulator.

```
$ sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
done

$ avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected package.
```

Help outputted by `avdmanager` tool:

```
  -g --tag     : The sys-img tag to use for the AVD. The default is to
                 auto-select if the platform has only one tag for its system
                 images.
```

What does it mean? What value should I put to this command-line key?

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html) does not even mention `--tag` parameter.